# Finding the paypal subscription end date upon cancel

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Upon cancel, I want to know how much time is left on the subscription's current billing cycle.

This [question -- paypal-ipn-get-subscription-end-date-recurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539764/paypal-ipn-get-subscription-end-date-recurring) got answered with a scenario where, upon the end of the cancellation period, a paypal event is sent at the end date.  In my case, however, I want to know in advanced how much time is remaining and record a future date (like a credit) and allow the user to use that up that time or give them an advance on their signing up again with another payment method (delay their next bill for example).

There is a `final_payment_date` under the deprecated billing agreements API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/ .. They say to use the subscription's API, but there is no end date available.  It is possible to use the subscription API to set things up and still use this API.

Unfortunately, because I don't see a non-deprecated end-date anywhere I think I may need to dive into the implementation here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscription-billing-cycles/?mark=cycle#

Paypal's Monthly example from the link above.  "[...] signs up on Tuesday, December 30, the subscriber is billed as follows:"

- Tuesday, December 30 = $25.99 USD
- Friday, January 30 = $25.99 USD
- Sunday, March 1= $25.99 USD
- Wednesday, April 1= $25.99USD

I'm close, instead of ending up on March 1st, I end up on March 2nd:

```js
> d=new Date('2017-12-30')
2017-12-30T00:00:00.000Z

> d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); d
2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z

> d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); d
2018-03-02T00:00:00.000Z

> d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); d
2018-04-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

In any event, looks like I need to save the subscription's first billing time and as long as the plan is still active and current on payments, I'll have to calculate when their next bill will be.

## BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED (webhook received)

Status `ACTIVE` resource id `I-79CLVAS5XM95`

As a point of reference, the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED **create_time** is `2020-06-05T19:45:08.868Z`.

- Save resource.id = `I-79CLVAS5XM95`
- Also save a date here, will use it to calculate the billing cycle

  - **resource.billing_info.next_billing_time** = `2020-06-05T19:35:10Z`
  - Or **resource.start_time** = `2020-06-05T07:00:00Z` ?
- Lookup **resource.plan_id** => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-1BC0896985601515LL3FNLCQ

  - Get **billing_cycles.frequency.interval_unit** = `DAY|WEEK|MONTH` and **[interval_count](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-frequency)**.  For example, if the interval_unit is DAY with an interval_count of 2, the subscription is billed once every two days.

```
plan.billing_cycles
[{
  pricing_scheme: {
    version: 1,
    fixed_price: { currency_code: 'USD', value: '0.01' },
    create_time: '2020-05-24T20:14:02Z',
    update_time: '2020-05-24T20:14:02Z'
  },
  frequency: { interval_unit: 'DAY', interval_count: 1 },
  tenure_type: 'REGULAR',
  sequence: 1,
  total_cycles: 0
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

> This question -- paypal-ipn-get-subscription-end-date-recurring got answered with a scenario where, upon the end of the cancellation period, a paypal event is sent at the end date. In my case, however, I want to know in advanced how much time is remaining and record a future date

To know in advance, use `resource.billing_info.next_billing_time`, not the resource.start_time (checkout time)

The example you quoted above:

```
Tuesday, December 30 = $25.99 USD
Friday, January 30 = $25.99 USD
Sunday, March 1= $25.99 USD
Wednesday, April 1= $25.99USD
```

Is due to February's shortness. February doesn't *have* a 30th to charge on, so PayPal opts to push the subscription forward to March 1 to keep everything roughly 30 days apart. This is explained in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: next_billing_time is not available when the client cancelled the subscription

Comment: Sure. Cancelled subscriptions don't have a next billing time. The next billing time is never.